# Best way to XSS protect jsonify output

Tags: python, flask

Which is the best way to protect from XSS-attacks via `jsonify()` in python Flask?

This is the Python (Flask) file:

```
testvar = {0: {'Name': 'df',
  'test1': 'sdf',
  'test2': 'sdf'},
 1: {'Name': 'dfdf',
  'test1': 'sdf',
  'test2': 'dfdf'},
 2: {'Name': 'dfdf',
  'test1': 'dfdfd',
  'test2': 'dfdfd<script>alert("test");</script>'}}

@app.route("/test")
def test():
    return jsonify(testvar)
```

This is the Javascript:

```
output_body = ""
$.getJSON('/test',function(data){
    $.each(data, function(key,val){
        output_body += "<tr>"
            for(property in val) {
                output_body += "<td>" + val[property] + "</td>"
            }
            output_body += "</tr>"
     });
$('table').html(output_body);
});
```

This code execute a js alert box.

Of course I can clean the data in js by escaping the < and >. But is there a good way to protect against a XSS attack in above example?

Comment: I don't think you need to, since JSON is just strings. As long as you don't do the js equivalent of `eval(string)`, you'll be fine.

Comment: Hi @Joost . Thanks for answer. But when I read the JSON in js (with $.getJSON and then loop via $.each) the <script></script> is executed.  One solution is of course to clean the data from html tags in js. But are there any good solutions for that in Python/Flask?

Comment: Please work out a full working example of this behavior, and we can have a look at it. Right now, it's just too little info to try and find out what's going on.

Comment: Thanks @Joost . I've updated the question.

Comment: I dont guess if there is anything related to flask, since u are updating the html, it will get executed, so u will have to validate data in the flask or just stop updating the html, get the json and then set it on your tag, but instead of html, set it as value or text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use bleach for this https://bleach.readthedocs.io/en/latest/clean.html : iterate over all the items and apply bleach.clean to them , then return the sanitized dictionary as json.

Or you can use a better javascript frontend (eg. react) to display the output (modern js frameworks escape this kind of stuff by default)